# How do I make it such that the user gets xp only once per minute, instead of once per message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on the leveling system of my discord bot. I want to make it such that the user gets xp only once per minute, no matter how many messages are sent. I can't figure it out and need some help. I tried adding a cooldown but nothing works.

This is the xp code:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
if (!message.guild) return;
if (message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

let randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;   
const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);

if (hasLeveledUp) 
{
const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
message.channel.send(`You leveled up to level ${user.level}!`);
}
                                 
if(cmd === "rank") 
{
    const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
    message.channel.send(`You are currently level **${user.level}**!`)
}

if(cmd === "lb") 
{
    const rawLeaderboard = await Levels.fetchLeaderboard(message.guild.id, 5);
    if (rawLeaderboard.length < 1) return reply(" Nobody's in the leaderboard yet..");
    
const leaderboard = Levels.computeLeaderboard(bot, rawLeaderboard); 
const lb = leaderboard.map(e => `${e.position}. ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: ${e.level}\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`);

message.channel.send(`${lb.join("\n\n")}`)

}
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a cooldown to awarding points on SQLite xp system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880816/adding-a-cooldown-to-awarding-points-on-sqlite-xp-system)

Answer (score 0):

I use that but it needs jsonfile and random

```
var stats = {};

if(fs.existsSync('stats.json')) {
    stats = jsonfile.readFileSync('stats.json');
}

if(message.author.bot) return;
if(!message.guild) return;

if(message.guild.id in stats === false){
    stats[message.guild.id] = {};
}

const guildstats = stats[message.guild.id];
if(message.author.id in guildstats === false){
    guildstats[message.author.id] = {
        xp: 0,
        level: 0,
        last_message: 0,
    };
}

const userstats = guildstats[message.author.id];
if(Date.now() - userstats.last_message > 60000) {
userstats.xp += Random.int(15, 25);
userstats.last_message = Date.now();

jsonfile.writeFileSync('stats.json', stats);

const xptonextlevel = 5 * Math.pow(userstats.level, 2) + 50 * userstats.level + 100;

if(userstats.xp >= xptonextlevel) {
    userstats.level++;
    userstats.xp - userstats.xp - xptonextlevel;
    message.reply('Has reached level ' + userstats.level)
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Archery, can you please add some more information? What is your goal, where exactly are you stuck and what did you already try to solve the problem?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.